# How to use notifyDataSetChanged() in recyclerview

Tags: android

I am developing an application in which data coming from server using xml parsing.In this am using intentservice to update an Ui in background and get data in broadcast receiver. 
Now my question is how to update UI in recycler view using the value that coming in broadcast receiver method onReceive?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in your **onReceive** method get the instance of your adapter and call it like

```
adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```